# MySQL subquery variable passing

Tags: mysql, variables, scope, subquery

table: User (id INT, firstname VARCHAR)

table: Blocklist (id INT, userid INT, blocked_userid INT)

```
SELECT user.id theID, user.firstname
FROM user
WHERE
NOT user.id = 1000
AND IF ((SELECT id FROM blocklist WHERE theID = ANY (SELECT blocked_userid FROM blocklist WHERE userid = 1000)), 0, (IF ((1000 = ANY (SELECT userid FROM blocklist WHERE blocked_userid = theID)),0,1)))
```

I want to return a list of all users not the current user, say... user 1000, that isn't blocked by that user or that isn't on the blocklist of another user.  Therefor it's a two-way system... you can't see people you blocked and you can see people who blocked you.  Problem is, I can't very well user "theID" in the subquery.  What would be the best way to tackle this?

Comment: Some sample data would really help understand what you need. Please post 3-4 users and their blocking relationships, and the wanted result for one or two of them. I have a feeling this can be done in a simpler way with `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`, but I am not sure exactly what you need to get.

Comment: insert into user (id, firstname) values (1, tom), (2, dick), (3, harry), (4, john);  insert into blocklist (id, userid, blocked_userid) values (1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (3, 1, 4), (4, 2, 3);

So running the desired query on userid = 1 would return nothing, as user 1 has blocked everyone. Running the desired query on userid = 2 would return user 4 only because 1 blocked 2 and 2 blocked 3 and the query should not return the same user.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on the sample data I think this does it:

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstname, b1.id, b2.id
FROM user AS u
JOIN user myUser ON myUser.id = 2
LEFT JOIN blocklist b1 ON u.id = b1.userid AND b1.blocked_userid = myUser.id
LEFT JOIN blocklist b2 ON u.id = b2.blocked_userid AND b2.userid = myUser.id
WHERE u.id != myUser.id
HAVING b1.id IS NULL AND b2.id IS NULL
```

If you really need to get rid of the two extra columns b1.id and b2.id:

```
SELECT t.theId, t.firstname FROM
       (SELECT u.id as theID, u.firstname, b1.id as b1, b2.id as b2
       FROM user AS u
       JOIN user myUser ON myUser.id = 2
       LEFT JOIN blocklist b1 ON u.id = b1.userid AND b1.blocked_userid = myUser.id
       LEFT JOIN blocklist b2 ON u.id = b2.blocked_userid AND b2.userid = myUser.id
       WHERE u.id != myUser.id
HAVING b1.id IS NULL AND b2.id IS NULL) as t
```